# Fresh MVC project is giving 500 error for RequestFilteringModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am getting following error for a fresh MVC project. Any idea how to fix it?
[image: 500 error]
Here are the things I have tried

- Uninstalled IIS Express 10, restarted, installed again
- Removed IIS from Programs and Features, restarted, added again

Comment: What is your default route?

Comment: Home .. it is a fresh project

Comment: Have you tried turning off [customErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx)? That should give you a full stack trace... though if you're running in debug, you ought to have a full stack trace when you hit the error.

Comment: Yes, this detail comes only when I have turned off customErrors

Comment: People, please don't downvote the question .. this is legitimate question and genuine problem

Comment: You are working on Windows 10? Does it have IIs10?

Comment: No, this Windows 8.1, VS 2013 SP4